# Unable to call a function in typeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, mediarecorder

I am trying to call recorder.start(); in my javascript but the console error shows recorder.start() is not a function. What am I doing wrong ?

```
const recordAudio=async function() {
  const stream = await  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
  const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
  const audioChunks = [];

  mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {
    audioChunks.push(event.data);
  });

  let start = function(){ mediaRecorder.start()};
 
};
const handleAction=function() {
const recorder = recordAudio();
const actionButton = document.getElementById('action');
actionButton.disabled = true;
recorder.start();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `recordAudio` function returns `Promise<void>`.

Return `mediaRecorder` instead, or return an object that contain that `start` method

```
return { start }
```

and then you can get the value of the instance with `const recorder = await recordAudio();`

Answer (score 0):

[It's a Promise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRZls.png)

What you get is a Promise instance not a function instance, so that the start() is not exist.

Maybe you can just call start() in recordAudio(), it will execute when your stream is prepared.